# Why is the result of called sqlcmd from my batch file unreliable?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

There is below `test.bat` which I expect to output count of specific name database `test` in an instance.

```
SET DB_SERVER_NAME=localhost
SET DB_DB_NAME=test
SET DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME=sa
SET DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD=test_sysad_pwd
for /F %%A in ('sqlcmd -S %DB_SERVER_NAME% -U %DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME% -P %DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD% -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '%DB_DB_NAME%'"') do set DBCNT=%%A
ECHO %DBCNT%  >> %~dp0\test.log 2>&1
```

`%DBCNT%` is sometimes `1` or `0` in `test.log` which I expect, but sometimes `%DBCNT%` doesn't contain a number.

What is wrong?

---

jeb and Mofi.
Thanks a lot. But current situation is more confusing.

Below is sqlcmd result directly called from command line.

```
 "sqlcmd.exe" -S "{servername}" -U "sa" -P "{pwd}" -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = 'testdb'"

-----------
          1
```

Below are matters pointed out to my program.
I doubt sqlcmd path can be specified in customer environment. I think sqlcmd.exe sometimes out of Windows folder.

A)A variable should be initialized.
B)Use "usebackq" syntax when a command contains "'".
C)%~dp0 ends with backslash.(Don't rely on kernel correction.)
D)Echo never writes something to handle STDERR (standard error). Use redirect directly to the log file.

Below is sample program:

```
REM /****************************************************************************/
SET DB_SERVER_NAME={servername}
SET DB_DB_NAME=testdb
SET DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME=sa
SET DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD={pwd}

REM /****************************************************************************/

chcp 437

REM original command
for /F %%A in ('sqlcmd -S %DB_SERVER_NAME% -U %DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME% -P %DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD% -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '%DB_DB_NAME%'"') do set DBCNT=%%A
>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#A#%DBCNT%

REM only use usebackq
SET DBCNT=0
for /F "usebackq" %%I in (`'sqlcmd -S %DB_SERVER_NAME% -U %DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME% -P %DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD% -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '%DB_DB_NAME%'"'`) do set DBCNT=%%I
>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#B#%DBCNT%

REM using remove single quotes several double quotes with absolute path sqlcmd
SET DBCNT=0
(for /F "usebackq" %%I in (`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -S "%DB_SERVER_NAME%" -U "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME%" -P "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD%" -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '%DB_DB_NAME%'"`) do set DBCNT=%%I) 2>>"%~dp0test.log"
>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#C#%DBCNT%

REM using remove single quotes several double quotes, removing double quotes
SET DBCNT=0
(for /F "usebackq" %%I in (`'sqlcmd.exe -S "%DB_SERVER_NAME%" -U "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME%" -P "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD%" -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '%DB_DB_NAME%'"'`) do set DBCNT=%%I) 2>>"%~dp0test.log"
>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#D#%DBCNT%

REM using remove single quotes several double quotes
SET DBCNT=0
(for /F "usebackq" %%I in (`sqlcmd.exe -S "%DB_SERVER_NAME%" -U "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME%" -P "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD%" -b -Q "set nocount on;SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '%DB_DB_NAME%'`) do set DBCNT=%%I) 2>>"%~dp0test.log"
>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#E#%DBCNT%
```

Below is result:

```
#A#1
#B#0
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
#C#0
#D#0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mofi, I got what I expected.

```
REM /****************************************************************************/
SET DB_SERVER_NAME={servername}
SET DB_DB_NAME=testdb
SET DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME=sa
SET DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD={pwd}

REM /****************************************************************************/


chcp 437
set DBCNT=0

REM duplicate double quote for ComSpec
(for /F "usebackq" %%I in (`""%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -S "%DB_SERVER_NAME%" -U "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME%" -P "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD%" -b -Q "set nocount on^;SELECT COUNT(NAME^) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME ^= '%DB_DB_NAME%'""`) do set DBCNT=%%I)

>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#E#%DBCNT%

set DBCNT=0

REM without absolute pass to sqlcmd
(for /F "usebackq" %%I in (`""sqlcmd.exe" -S "%DB_SERVER_NAME%" -U "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_NAME%" -P "%DB_SYSADMIN_LOGIN_PWD%" -b -Q "set nocount on^;SELECT COUNT(NAME^) FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME ^= '%DB_DB_NAME%'""`) do set DBCNT=%%I)

>>"%~dp0test.log" echo(#F#%DBCNT%

pause
```

Result test.log is below.

```
#E#1
#F#1
```